# Calling ajax returned outside the function?

Tags: ajax, function

I am trying to call the ajax returned outside its function, below is the code I tried but didn't work.

```
var names;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/get_upcoming.php'
}).success(function (data) {
    names = data[1];
});

alert(names);
```

Comment: It didn't work is too generic.... But there could be an obvious reason which is asked most frequently here

Comment: No `scope` for `names` outside `success` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because success function is callback function and called when ajax request get the response , so instead try this

```
var names;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/get_upcoming.php',
    success: performOperation
});



function performOperation(data)
{
    // write your code here 
    names = data[1];
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it, but i want to use names on other function. That's the whole idea

Comment: If you want to perform some opertation or activty after ajax request you need to put it in success function only . Because when request is going to complete,nobody knows , so its better practice to create a function and you write what you want to do and call it in success function

Comment: Nope, you are not helping.

Comment: Now you are helping instead of suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think alert() executes before the response comes back from the server. 
put console.log() and remove the alert and see the order of executions.